# Create a docstring for an enum for Xcode 5's Quick H⁣elp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums, documentation, docstring

I want to document an enum in Xcode 5 so that I can see my docstring as Quick Help, in the autocomplete popup.  For example, if I do this:

```
//! Better than a normal int!
typedef int superint;
```

then I can type `superi` and the popup shows `superint`, and at the bottom of the popup it shows "Better than a normal int!".

I can't seem to figure out any way to get this to work for an enum, though.  My enum looks like this:

```
typedef enum: unsigned int {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
} abc_t;
```

Prepending a `//!` (or `///` or `/**`) line doesn't work in this case.  I type "abc_" and the completion appears in the popup, but there is no docstring at the bottom.

One thought I had was that Apple might better support using their NS_ENUM() macro, but `//!` on the line before a `typedef NS_ENUM(...) { ... }` doesn't work, either.

I looked through the Foundation headers for examples where this worked, but I think they must be doing something special.  For example, `NSXMLParserError` is an enum which shows a docstring in the autocomplete popup (if you type "NSXMLParserE"), but in NSXmlParser.h it has an  ordinary `//` comment on the line before it.  Following this style in my own code does not show a docstring in the popup.

Comment: Oddly, the individual members _do_ show their descriptions [in the popup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5OXf3.png) when [they each have docstrings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gJcVv.png). I also see the descriptions in when ⌥-clicking on the [type](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OSMxq.png) and the [values](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hy0WM.png).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work, but it's kind of ugly:

```
typedef enum: unsigned int {
    //! First letter
    ABC_A = 1,
    //! Second letter
    ABC_B = 2,
    //! Third letter
    ABC_C = 3,
}
//! Now I know my ABC's.
abc_t;
```

I would love to have a solution that lets me keep the docstring *above* the declaration, like it is in every other context.

Comment: Josh: Good idea.  That works for the enum type itself, but the autocomplete for the items shows their type as "enum <anonymous> ABC_A", which isn't ideal.

Comment: Then again, showing "enum <anonymous>" is exactly what the built-in documentation does.

Answer (score 0):

NS_ENUM can be documented.
Using whichever multiline style you like, at least within Xcode 6 in the inspector, it respects the @abstract for the overall description and follows it with each member if you use @field

```
/*!
@abstract NSUInteger typedef to simplify stuff.
@field EnvironmentNumberMIN one.
*/
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, EnvironmentNumber) {
/// Lower floor. Use for validation.
EnvironmentNumberMIN    = 0,
....
```

For an old style enum, it works but doesn't put the members on discrete new lines like it does with NS_ENUM